# Dart list.take - Error: type 'SubListIterable<myClass>' is not a subtype of type List<myClass>

Tags: list, dart

I am trying to limit the length of a list to x items like this

```
List<int> myObjects = [1,22,33,52,1,52,12,12,43];      
myObjects = myObjects.take(4);
```

but then I am getting the error in the title. Any tips please?

Comment: add .toList() after your .take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [toList()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/toList.html) on the result of `take(4)` since [take(x)](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-collection/ListQueue/take.html) returns an [Iterable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable-class.html) instead of a [List](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html)

So the second line should be:

```
myObjects = myObjects.take(4).toList();
```

Comment: Or alternative: `myObjects = [...myObjects.take(4)];` or (in this case) do: `myObjects = myObjects.sublist(0, 4)`.